# MongoDB search for specific string in collectionm, put to list

Tags: c#, mongodb

I have a mongoDB database&collection set up.

My collection objects look like this:

```
_id = "string"
details = {
    more_vars = "string"
}
```

From the `details` object I want to get a specific variables' value (`more_vars` returns `string`). and then possibly get all of them to a list so I can easily search through it.

Code so far

```
public static void Connect()
{
    var client = new MongoClient("conntected through srv");
    var database = client.GetDatabase("monza");
    var collection = database.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("whitelist");
    var filter = collection.Find(new BsonDocument()).ToList();
    foreach(BsonDocument doc in filter)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(doc.ToString());
    }
    
}
```

output: Get all objects in collection
output I'd want: Get only a specific key's value and then for each object put that key into a list (amybe an array?)

Comment: Are you asking how to query "details.more_vars" for the value "string"? If not, I'm not really following.

Comment: Yes but then for earch object in the collection

Comment: As far as I understand you just need use `SetFields` like `var filter = collection.Find(new BsonDocument()).SetFields(Fields.Include("details")).ToList();`

Comment: Or `var filter = collection.Find(new BsonDocument()).Project(d => new { d.details }).ToList();`

Comment: @SelimYildiz When trying I get `'BsonDocument' does not contain a definition for 'details' and no accessible extension method 'details' accepting a first argument of type 'BsonDocument' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?`

Comment: There should be property called  `details` in `BsonDocument`, what is your `BsonDocument` class definition?

Comment: The only thing I do related wiith a `BsonDocument` is `var collection = database.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("whitelist");`

Comment: If you just need that list of string  then use dynamic `var collection = database.GetCollection<dynamic>("whitelist");
 var filter = collection.Find(Builders<dynamic>.Filter.Empty).Project(d => new { d.details }).ToList();`

Comment: Error; `an expression tree may not contain a dynamic operation`